# Can't access to the page content

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a problem while trying to get an element by name "login". It should return 1 if there is at least one HTML input with this name. But it doesn't work! Chrome console doesn't write any errors.

smart.js

```
chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener(function(){
    console.log("And finally " + document.getElementsByName("login").length);
}
```

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Test",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Test app",
  "permissions": [ "background", "tts", "storage", "webNavigation", "activeTab", "tabs" ],

  "background": { "scripts": ["my.js"] },

  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "my.html"
  },
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'",

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
      "js": ["smart.js"]
    }
  ],
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you should move these function `chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener` to background script. The problem is that content script can't handle it. Then if you need to send data from background script use message passing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try using `chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener()` instead. I'm using it like that:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(
  function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) { 
    if (changeInfo.status == 'complete') {
     ...
    } 
  }
);
```

Comment: But event listener doesn't help here. The problem is in accessing the content of the page